# Fetch data from database and send it in an email using unix script

Tags: sql, shell, unix, plsql, sh

I have a table like below.

```
Partner_id  Transmission_id  Filename  Email_Contact
Partner1     123             file1     email1@abc.com
Partner1     456             file2     email1@abc.com
partner1     987             file3     email2@abc.com
partner2     532             file4     email3@abc.com
partner2     234             file5     email4@abc.com
partner3     795             file6     email5@abc.com
partner3     367             file7     email5@abc.com
```

I am writing a unix script to fetch data from database and send filename to email addresses.
e.g: for partner1 single email should be sent to email1@abc.com and email2@abc.com containing file1,file2 and file3 in body and partner1 in subject.
I am not good in unix. Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`#!bin/bash
Partner_ID=$(sqlplus -s dbusernameg@ora12c/dbpassword <<END
       SELECT Partner_id  FROM table name;
END
)
file_name=$(sqlplus -s dbusernameg@ora12c/dbpassword <<END
       SELECT Filename FROM table name;
END
)
email_ID=$(sqlplus -s dbusernameg@ora12c/dbpassword <<END
       SELECT Email_Contact FROM table name;
END
)
echo '$file_name' | mail -s '$Partner_ID' $email_ID`

Hope it helps...